# I am using phantom wallet and trying to sign typed data

Tags: phantom, phantom-wallet, message

Hi I am trying to sign a message using solana/wallet-adapter and gets error: "Cannot sign transaction using sign message"

code example below, Solflare and Wallet Connect treats Uint8Array encoded message fine, so trying to figure out

```
import { serialize } from 'borsh';
const message = new Mail({
from: new Person({
name: 'Cow',
wallet: '0xCD2a3d9F938E13CD947Ec05AbC7FE734Df8DD826'
}),
to: new Person({
name: 'Bob',
wallet: '0xbBbBBBBbbBBBbbbBbbBbbbbBBbBbbbbBbBbbBBbB'
}),
contents: 'Hello, Bob!'
});
// Serialize the data
const serializedData = serialize(schema, message);
// Sign the serialized data
const signature = await phantomWalletProvider.signMessage(serializedData);
```

this variant doesnt work also:

```
signature = await walletProvider.signMessage(new TextEncoder().encode(JSON.stringify(message)));
```

Answer (score 3):

it looks like you have some Ethereum addresses in that message you're signing. Could you please confirm if you're trying to sign a message on Solana? If so, could you please double check that you are passing either a **hex** or **UTF-8** encoded string as a Uint8Array? Phantom's `signMessage` method on Solana will only accept UTF-8 or hex encoded strings (see [docs](https://docs.phantom.app/solana/signing-a-message)). For a live example, please see our [sandbox](https://r3byv.csb.app/) and its accompanying [signMessage](https://github.com/phantom/sandbox/blob/b57fdd0e65ce4f01290141a01e33d17fd2f539b9/src/App.tsx#L242) function.

Comment: I changed to solana addresses, with same result. that is just an example of some serialized object to be subscribed